# How to display a notification from service when activity gets destroyed

Tags: android, service, android-notifications

Here my scenario in which i am starting a service from an Activity which play music in background. When i press back button on this activity, activity get destroyed. but service is still running in background. I want to show a notification to user when this activity get destroyed so that they can play/pause/stop audio from notification. but i dont want notification to be displayed when the service get started.

below is my activity code :

```
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PlayBackgroundAudioActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AudioServiceBinder audioServiceBinder = null;

    private Handler audioProgressUpdateHandler = null;

    // Show played audio progress.
    private ProgressBar backgroundAudioProgress;

    private TextView audioFileUrlTextView;

    // This service connection object is the bridge between activity and background service.
    private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
            // Cast and assign background service's onBind method returned iBander object.
            audioServiceBinder = (AudioServiceBinder) iBinder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {

        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_background_audio);

        setTitle("dev2qa.com - Play Audio Use Background Service");

        // Bind background audio service when activity is created.
        bindAudioService();

        final String audioFileUrl = "http://www.dev2qa.com/demo/media/test.mp3";

        backgroundAudioProgress = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.play_audio_in_background_service_progressbar);

        // Get audio file url textview.
        audioFileUrlTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.audio_file_url_text_view);
        if(audioFileUrlTextView != null)
        {
            // Show web audio file url in the text view.
            audioFileUrlTextView.setText("Audio File Url. \r\n" + audioFileUrl);
        }

        // Click this button to start play audio in a background service.
        Button startBackgroundAudio = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start_audio_in_background);
        startBackgroundAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Set web audio file url
                audioServiceBinder.setAudioFileUrl(audioFileUrl);

                // Web audio is a stream audio.
                audioServiceBinder.setStreamAudio(true);

                // Set application context.
                audioServiceBinder.setContext(getApplicationContext());

                // Initialize audio progress bar updater Handler object.
                createAudioProgressbarUpdater();
                audioServiceBinder.setAudioProgressUpdateHandler(audioProgressUpdateHandler);

                // Start audio in background service.
                audioServiceBinder.startAudio();

                backgroundAudioProgress.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start play web audio file.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        // Click this button to pause the audio played in background service.
        Button pauseBackgroundAudio = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pause_audio_in_background);
        pauseBackgroundAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                audioServiceBinder.pauseAudio();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Play web audio file is paused.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        // Click this button to stop the media player in background service.
        Button stopBackgroundAudio = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop_audio_in_background);
        stopBackgroundAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                audioServiceBinder.stopAudio();
                backgroundAudioProgress.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stop play web audio file.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    // Bind background service with caller activity. Then this activity can use
    // background service's AudioServiceBinder instance to invoke related methods.
    private void bindAudioService()
    {
        if(audioServiceBinder == null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(PlayBackgroundAudioActivity.this, AudioService.class);

            // Below code will invoke serviceConnection's onServiceConnected method.
            bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        }
    }

    // Unbound background audio service with caller activity.
    private void unBoundAudioService()
    {
        if(audioServiceBinder != null) {
            unbindService(serviceConnection);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // Unbound background audio service when activity is destroyed.
        unBoundAudioService();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    // Create audio player progressbar updater.
    // This updater is used to update progressbar to reflect audio play process.
    private void createAudioProgressbarUpdater()
    {
        /* Initialize audio progress handler. */
        if(audioProgressUpdateHandler==null) {
            audioProgressUpdateHandler = new Handler() {
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    // The update process message is sent from AudioServiceBinder class's thread object.
                    if (msg.what == audioServiceBinder.UPDATE_AUDIO_PROGRESS_BAR) {

                        if( audioServiceBinder != null) {
                            // Calculate the percentage.
                            int currProgress =audioServiceBinder.getAudioProgress();

                            // Update progressbar. Make the value 10 times to show more clear UI change.
                            backgroundAudioProgress.setProgress(currProgress*10);
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        startActivity(new Intent(PlayBackgroundAudioActivity.this,ForeGroundService.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

below is my service code:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class AudioService extends Service {

    private AudioServiceBinder audioServiceBinder = new AudioServiceBinder();

    public AudioService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return audioServiceBinder;
    }
}
```

below is myaudio binder class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by Jerry on 2/15/2018.
 */

public class AudioServiceBinder extends Binder {

    // Save local audio file uri ( local storage file. ).
    private Uri audioFileUri = null;

    // Save web audio file url.
    private String audioFileUrl = "";

    // Check if stream audio.
    private boolean streamAudio = false;

    // Media player that play audio.
    private MediaPlayer audioPlayer = null;

    // Caller activity context, used when play local audio file.
    private Context context = null;

    // This Handler object is a reference to the caller activity's Handler.
    // In the caller activity's handler, it will update the audio play progress.
    private Handler audioProgressUpdateHandler;

    // This is the message signal that inform audio progress updater to update audio progress.
    public final int UPDATE_AUDIO_PROGRESS_BAR = 1;

    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public String getAudioFileUrl() {
        return audioFileUrl;
    }

    public void setAudioFileUrl(String audioFileUrl) {
        this.audioFileUrl = audioFileUrl;
    }

    public boolean isStreamAudio() {
        return streamAudio;
    }

    public void setStreamAudio(boolean streamAudio) {
        this.streamAudio = streamAudio;
    }

    public Uri getAudioFileUri() {
        return audioFileUri;
    }

    public void setAudioFileUri(Uri audioFileUri) {
        this.audioFileUri = audioFileUri;
    }

    public Handler getAudioProgressUpdateHandler() {
        return audioProgressUpdateHandler;
    }

    public void setAudioProgressUpdateHandler(Handler audioProgressUpdateHandler) {
        this.audioProgressUpdateHandler = audioProgressUpdateHandler;
    }

    // Start play audio.
    public void startAudio()
    {
        initAudioPlayer();
        if(audioPlayer!=null) {
            audioPlayer.start();
        }
    }

    // Pause playing audio.
    public void pauseAudio()
    {
        if(audioPlayer!=null) {
            audioPlayer.pause();
        }
    }

    // Stop play audio.
    public void stopAudio()
    {
        if(audioPlayer!=null) {
            audioPlayer.stop();
            destroyAudioPlayer();
        }
    }

    // Initialise audio player.
    private void initAudioPlayer()
    {
        try {
            if (audioPlayer == null) {
                audioPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(getAudioFileUrl())) {
                    if (isStreamAudio()) {
                        audioPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    }
                    audioPlayer.setDataSource(getAudioFileUrl());
                } else {
                    audioPlayer.setDataSource(getContext(), getAudioFileUri());
                }

                audioPlayer.prepare();

                // This thread object will send update audio progress message to caller activity every 1 second.
                Thread updateAudioProgressThread = new Thread()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        while(true)
                        {
                            // Create update audio progress message.
                            Message updateAudioProgressMsg = new Message();
                            updateAudioProgressMsg.what = UPDATE_AUDIO_PROGRESS_BAR;

                            // Send the message to caller activity's update audio prgressbar Handler object.
                            audioProgressUpdateHandler.sendMessage(updateAudioProgressMsg);

                            // Sleep one second.
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            }catch(InterruptedException ex)
                            {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
                // Run above thread object.
                updateAudioProgressThread.start();
            }
        }catch(IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Destroy audio player.
    private void destroyAudioPlayer()
    {
        if(audioPlayer!=null)
        {
            if(audioPlayer.isPlaying())
            {
                audioPlayer.stop();
            }

            audioPlayer.release();

            audioPlayer = null;
        }
    }

    // Return current audio play position.
    public int getCurrentAudioPosition()
    {
        int ret = 0;
        if(audioPlayer != null)
        {
            ret = audioPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        }
        return ret;
    }

    // Return total audio file duration.
    public int getTotalAudioDuration()
    {
        int ret = 0;
        if(audioPlayer != null)
        {
            ret = audioPlayer.getDuration();
        }
        return ret;
    }

    // Return current audio player progress value.
    public int getAudioProgress()
    {
        int ret = 0;
        int currAudioPosition = getCurrentAudioPosition();
        int totalAudioDuration = getTotalAudioDuration();
        if(totalAudioDuration > 0) {
            ret = (currAudioPosition * 100) / totalAudioDuration;
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you should reconsider the time when your notification is shown. Since the [onDestroy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()) method of an activity may not be always called, I would prefer to use another point when to display your notification. You should be also aware of the new [restrictions regarding background services](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) since android 8 (API 26), if you do not explicitly *mark* them as a foreground service, then they might be killed by the OS while the app is in the background.

So, for your purpose it might be an option to use the method [startForeground](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)) with a notification id and call it when your activity is going to the background (e.g. at onStop), then it will display the notification (which is the requirement for keeping the service in the foreground). If you decide to go back to your activity after some time, you may call [stopForeground](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopForeground(boolean)) to stop the foreground mode and dismiss your notification.

Comment: how will i handle my listner if both activity and service get killed. where should i keep my audio listner

Comment: What do you mean by `audio listener`, your `AudioServiceBinder`? Well, basically I would keep those references (like the ``MediaPlayer`) in the service and use the binder class only as an interface for your communication with the activities. But as you've asked, if your service and all activities will get killed, then there is no chance to reclaim your references back.

Comment: ino i mean if i keep switching between activity and service which is if back press from activity service will display notification and if activity is running i need hide notification but service is still running i dont want my service to be restarted

Comment: There is actually no switching - your service will always run in the background as long as it is stopped manually or by the system. The service takes care about the audio player, so that playing the audio is not interrupted by changing the states of your activities. Your activity can still communicate with the service (via the binder) and if you know that your activity is running, you can define a method at your binder class to notify the service that it can hide the notification (as discussed by calling stopForeground).

Comment: ohh ok got it. i thought stopForeground will stop the service however it will remove the notification and i can display the notification again using binder from activity. i am so sorry about this

Comment: Np, I'm glad I could help.